# Core Data/Swift 3 - Nil Values being randomly added to core data NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

I have a core data model used to hold the leaderboards for my spritekit game.
However, for some reason the first time I ran my game when it passed to the leaderboard's table view controller an error occurred.

After adding breakpoints and trying to debug it, I found out for some reason a set of data was already present in the core data model with `nil` values which was giving the error.

I found this after printing the `NSManagedObject` I use to hold the data,
the image below shows what I mean:

[image]

My issue is I haven't at any point added this values.
However, every time the app is ran they appear.
I have gone through my code several times and cannot seem to find why it keeps getting added.
It isn't as simple as not force unwrapping the values as by doing this all it does is not give an error when running the code.
However, it still shows a set of data equal to nil when populating the table view, which I cannot have.
My code is as follows:

**App Delegate**

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "ScoreModel")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
        if let error = error as NSError? {
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
    })
    return container
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Leaderboard Table View Controller Swift File**

```
import CoreData

class LeaderboardTableVC: UITableViewController {

var finishedGame = 0 
var gameScore:Int! = 0
var name:String!
var date:String!
var score:Int!
var scoreData = [NSManagedObject]()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Scores")
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "date", ascending: false)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

        do {
            let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            scoreData = results as! [NSManagedObject]
            print(scoreData)
            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                name = result.value(forKey: "name") as? String
                date = result.value(forKey: "date") as? String
                score = result.value(forKey: "score") as? Int

                }

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Any idea as to why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: I wonder why a completely identical question was posted under a different user account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39780893/nil-values-appearing-without-being-added-to-core-data-swift-3.

Comment: got the login to my old account back so switched back to it as I have a higher reputation number on this one

Answer (score 0):

In CoreData, all of the properties defined to be in an entity are included in each instance of the entity when it is created.  If the property is defined as optional, you can create an instance of the entity without specifying values for the property and the value of the property will be nil - much as the values of the name and date vars start as nil in the Class definition you included.  In that sense, you added the nil values by the act of creating an instance of the NSManagedObject.

Since this is pretty much unavoidable, you'll need to either 1) add values to the fields when you add the entity instance (and you could force your hand by making these non-optional), or 2) add guards or tests to avoid trying to unwrap the property fields when they're nil.

Comment: I've confused cause I have previously used Core Data in a previous project and this didn't occur.  Do you have any alternative method or fix which would resolve this issue ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you'd want to see differently if the fields weren't nil-valued but simply "not there". If they are nil, you can't force unwrap the properties without an error anyway.  Instead, you'll have to test for nil (guard, conditional chaining, or whatever) and simply not show them when they're nil, which seems to be what you're after.  Given that it's a tableView, if you're using a fetchedResultsController you'd handle this in the configureCell delegate function by not showing the fields if they're nil (or show a "Not Yet Available" sort of label if you want to be fancier.